# How to implement 2d graphics in android?

Tags: android, core-graphics

I am new to android.

I want to develop a 2d graphical program.

My requirement is when i am giving the values of x-axis, y axis values and press triangle it will form triangle ,press circle it will circle ....

If any one has idea please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are many tutorials out there.

You can follow this one: http://www.droidnova.com/2d-tutorial-series-part-i,770.html